# Segfault in Tranposed matrix multiplication with .eval() with Eigen 3 library

Tags: c++, eigen

I added two `.eval()` just in case. I got no compilation error, and no run time warning. Just segfault.

Thanks for helping me to fix this.

Test:

```
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
#include <iostream>
using namespace Eigen;

int main() {
    Matrix<float, Dynamic, Dynamic> mat_b;
    Matrix<float, Dynamic, Dynamic> mat_c;

    mat_b << 1.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5,
             0.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.5,
             1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
             0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0;

    mat_c << 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
             0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
             1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
             1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0;

    std::cout << (mat_b.transpose().eval() * mat_c).eval() << "\n";
}
```

Result:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Check the call stack, where it came from.

Comment: I know I can use debugger, but that will only step into the internal of the library. Won't help me as a user of the library.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: most of the time, I get some kind of runtime warning, unless I `#define EIGEN_NO_DEBUG`. But no run time warning this time. just segfault.

Comment: If the code that I write is wrong, I use debugger. If it involves the internal of a library not made by me, I ask.

Comment: ... why? We didn't write the library either.

Comment: What sizes you expect `mat_b`, `mat_c` and result one to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [documentatipon](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialAdvancedInitialization.html)

> The comma initializer
>
> Eigen offers a comma initializer syntax which allows the user to easily set all the coefficients of a matrix, vector or array. Simply list the coefficients, starting at the top-left corner and moving from left to right and from the top to the bottom. **The size of the object needs to be specified beforehand**. If you list too few or too many coefficients, Eigen will complain.

emphasis is mine. If you expect that `Matrix` ctor would deduce size from your formatting, that simply not possible in C++. Looks like you created 16x1 and 24x1 matrix and then try to multiply 1x16 (transposed first one) to 24x1 which is not legal.

Comment: They could add an assert to the `<<` operator to check if the dimension of the object is specified. Then no one will ask this kind of question again.

Comment: Contact library creator/supporters and suggest, I am not related to them.

Comment: They will see this. They always check here.